# DataGrip skip lines during execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, datagrip

Why does DataGrip skip lines when I execute my script?

[image]

It seems like it skips all the lines highlighted in green.

Isn't there any option which tells DataGrip to execute every line? I've been searching for several hours and even days to find this #$@!& option... 
**(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻**

**Note:** I tried in console, from file, clicking the play button (**▸**), ..... but it still skip the green lines.

Comment: What if Select All (Cmd+A) and then execute?

Comment: @moscas Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These skipped statements are sqlplus statements. They are not part of oracle sql syntax (they are interpreted by sqlplus utility), so not supported by datagrip.

Comment: So DataGrip doesn't support SQLPlus? Only SQL?

Comment: DG supports highlighting and editing of SqlPlus scripts and execution of sql part of that scripts. SqlPlus scripts should be executed through sqlplus utility